# How do I include Bootstrap styling in Svelte with webpacker

Tags: webpack, sass, svelte, svelte-3

I am developing an application using Ruby-on-Rails for the backend and Svelte for the frontend.  As its RoR, Svelte is compiled using Webpacker (using RoR Webpack installation of Svelte).  I am using Bootstrap 4 to style the pages.  While I am able to use the Bootstrap classes in the HTML parts of a Svelte file, I am not able to use `@extend` in the `style` section unless I include `Bootstrap` in the specific component.

Here are my files.  The load process is controlled by `config/webpack/loaders/svelte.js`:

```js
const autoPreprocess = require('svelte-preprocess');

module.exports = {
  test: /\.svelte(\.erb)?$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'svelte-loader',
    options: {
      dev: true,
      hotReload: false,
      preprocess: autoPreprocess()
    }
  }
};
```

The svelte application is launched in the browser by an HTML file loading the following scripts in `app/javascript/packs/start_svelte.js`:

```js
/* eslint no-console: 0 */

// This file provides the mechanism to load the Svelte app itself.  Invoked from application.html.erb
import 'bootstrap';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all';

import App from "../components/App.svelte";

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const app = new App({
    target: document.body,
    props: {
      name: 'Svelte'
    }
  });

  window.app = app;
});
```

This is `app/javascript/components/App.svelte` loaded from the above:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import Router from 'svelte-spa-router'
</script>

<style lang="scss" global>
  @import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
</style>

<!-- Navigation -->
... core page structure

<Router {routes}/>
```

I have a component file `ExpenseEntryTable.svelte`.  I can use the bootstrap classes directly within the HTML with no issues.  However, I can only use them in the  section if I include the Bootstrap.scss file locally.  Here is my component file (abreviated):

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { flip } from 'svelte/animate';

    import ExpenseEntryRow from "./ExpenseEntryRow.svelte";
    import RailsFields from "./RailsFields.svelte";

    export let expenseEntries;

    ... code to handle some interactive stuff
</script>

<div class="expenses-claim-table">
    <div class="form col-12">
        <div id="expense-entries-header" class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-1">Seq</div>
            <div class="form-group col-1">Date</div>

           ... more columns 
        </div>
    </div>

   ... more stuff to do with the column
</div>

<style lang="scss">
    @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"; // without this compiler throws error two lines down

    .expenses-claim-table {
        @extend .list-group;  // without local import this line generates the error
    }
</style>
```

Here is the error dump from the Svelte compiler if the @include is not included locally:

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/components/ExpenseEntryTable.svelte
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/svelte-loader/index.js):
Error: ".expenses-claim-table" failed to @extend ".list-group".
The selector ".list-group" was not found.
Use "@extend .list-group !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.
```

I would rather not include @import on every page I want to use Bootstrap classes and variables in the `<style>` section, and thought the global flag in App.svelte would make this unnecessary.  Any suggestions?